# How to install previous gitlab ce version using omnibus?

Tags: gitlab, centos7, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-ce, git-server

How to install any previous version of **GitLab CE** while using **GitLab Omnibus installation**?

As far as I know **Omnibus installation** always installs the **latest GitLab version** (Current 11.7) and doesn’t support different versions while restoring backup, But I have a backup of my previous Gitlab Version (10.7.3).
So If there is anyway to install **previous GitLab 10.7.3 (Omnibus)**, I will be able to restore my backup.

Server-OS: CentOS-7(64bit) - (Self Hosted Gitlab Community Edition)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check available gitlab versions
and to install certain version.

```
yum --showduplicates list gitlab-ce

yum install gitlab-ce-<version info>
```